# Class Loader (java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file)

Tags: java, bytecode, .class-file

I am writing my own classloader, that is changing stuff in the constantpool of the classes.
I know that my error is caused by my changes and not the class loader or the default class.

I need to know where i have to fine the signature of the classfile, and how I can change it so my class is not read as corrupted.

I used [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) site to read and change my constant pool, but on the site is nothing about a file signature.

I think it might be hidden in the Attribute Table, but im not shure about that 
and even if I'm able to find it i have no idea how to recreate the signature to get the file working again.

I hope somebody is able to help me.

-Leo

Edit:
I found something about the bytecode verifier [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.2.2), but I still don't realy understand how it works.

Comment: use some bytecode mainipulation libary to avoid errors. See http://java-source.net/open-source/bytecode-libraries

Comment: Agree with @Alexi ... but I'd also ask why you think you need to do this, because unless you're doing something EXTREMELY weird you're probably wrong. You may also want to look up topics like "code injection", which are among the few on-the-fly class modifications that are commonly used. " ... Three things are most dangerous: / Connectors that corrode / Unproven algorithms, and / Self-modifying code ... "

Comment: If you give me the classfile, I can tell you what's wrong with it. As there question currently stands, there's not enough information to help.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Thanks thats the type of thing that I was searching for.

Comment: @Antimony The problem is not in my code. The Code is working fine. My problem is that i changed something in the class bytecode, but the java class loader is seeing my class as corrupted, and won't load it.

Comment: @CoderCloud If the class loader tells you that the class is corrupted, the problem **is** in your code. Were do you expect the problem otherwise, in the JVM developed and improved by experts over a twenty years period? Use the [Class File Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) and try to read your own class and you will find the error. Note that the error message “Truncated class file” gives you a hint about the kind of problem.

Comment: Most likely you messed up one of the length fields. Writing classfiles by hand directly in binary is error-prone and not for the faint of heart. I remember that even for the simplest classes, I usually made several mistakes, and that was with the JVM spec for reference.

Comment: @Holger My code worked fine, but my class contained a BytecodeVerifier attribute. After i removed the attribute, my class loaded without problems. I'm now using bcel to change my class bytes, and its working perfectly.

Comment: @CoderCloud: What the hell shall a “BytecodeVerifier attribute” be? It sounds like you simply had a *broken* attribute there and by removing it you fixed your class file.

Comment: @Holger [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.2.2). The "Bytecode Verifier" is used to prevent the jvm from loading classes, that were be accidently damaged while download or sth. like that, and lets the classloader throw a TruncatedClassFile exception.

Comment: @CoderCloud: That’s the point as said for days now, the Verifier rejects classes that are *damaged* and your class was rejected because it *was* damaged and the only possible reason was because *your* code produced a damaged class. So stop repeating that your code was working fine when it actually produced a broken class file. And still your sentence “my class contained a BytecodeVerifier attribute” makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Holger My ClassPool was fine, my Problem was, that the way i changed my CP affected the way that other attributes worked, so the didn't work as they should. The CP manipulator was fine, but i needed to change the attributes too to get the class working again.